# Looking for Math books recommendations to study Electronics

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, education, signal-processing

My background is the very basics, and I mean, literally, I can add, sub,mul,div and a little of algebra (near, nothing) and that's it.

As you can see I need the best Total Beginner Book(s) that can allows me to read every basic (and maybe and not so basic) electronic text out there without knowledge 'gaps' of math.

I have some of these books, but the fact that I don't know what a Fourier series is (mentioned in some electronic book I own) is what prompts me to fill the gap first before going on that journey, so what I'm asking is a chronological order of books for this, thanks.

Comment: What kinds of "electronics"-related things are you trying to learn?  Since you mention Fourier analysis, you're presumably looking into some kind of signal processing.

Comment: In order to learn about Fourier series, I'd say that the bare minimum you need is the basics of differential/integral calculus.  Any understanding of linear algebra and complex analysis (or the complex numbers in general) will help immensely, but is not strictly necessary.

Comment: I would recommend that you also try posting this question on the [electrical engineering SE site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) and/or the [DSP SE site](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom basically everything related to mosfets.

Comment: As in how to use them in logical circuits, or the physics behind how they work, or everything?  Anyway, it doesn't seem like you'll be needing Fourier analysis afterall, or much math for that matter

Comment: Well I mentioned fourier as an example to demonstrate that my math knowledge is poor, however I only need a good book that cements a base

Comment: for reading electronics books in general.

Comment: Again, I recommend that you try asking this question on a different site